# Unable to write to directory

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04

I can't write to a directory where my user should belong to the directory's group...

```
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data root   30 Sep 17 13:34 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 twentyeleven
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 twentyten

dp : dp adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare www-pub
```

Here is the updated listing...

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data root   28 Sep 17 13:34 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 plugins
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 themes
dp@acme:/var/www/stlit/wp-content$ cd themes
dp@acme:/var/www/stlit/wp-content/themes$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data root   30 Sep 17 13:34 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 twentyeleven
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root 4096 Sep 17 13:34 twentyten
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Please provide a complete directory listing by ``ls -al`` (this includes the ``.`` and ``..``) and the output of the command ``id``. My best guess now is that you're not in the ``root`` group (you shouldn't) and that you want to change the group of the directory to one you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the listing above

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data root .....
```

This means, that the first *name* `www-data` is the "owner" of the file, and the second one `root` is the "group" the file belongs to.

And since your user isn't in the `root` group (and it shouldn't!), you cannot modify the file, as only the owner and group have full access on the files.

1. To change the group of a file you need to use

   ```
   sudo chgrp "new-group-name" file
   ```
2. To change the owner of a file you need to use

   ```
   sudo chown "new-owner-name" file
   ```
3. If you want to change both, you can do it in a single command with:

   ```
   sudo chown "new-owner-name":"new-group-name" file
   ```

My best guess is that you needed to use `chgrp` but instead you used `chown`

Comment: I think you are correct!  As I said I am a newbie...thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay...I am just testing this now...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean either of `twentyeleven` or `twentyten` in that file listing, the group there is root, and the user is www-data, who owns those directories.

You will need to change the group of the files to the www-data group as well if you wish to write to them as that user. You probably want to do `sudo chgrp -R www-data .` in the directory containing those files and directories you want to edit as your user.